# XMLParser giving error ''Cannot set property value of undefined''

Tags: javascript, xml, react-native, xml-parsing

I am working in React Native App and simply trying to execute this piece of code

```js
fetch('https://ad13.adfarm1.adition.com/banner?sid=3915124&wpt=X.xml')
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log("WorkingTillHere",responseJson)
    xml_Img = new XMLParser().parseFromString(responseJson);    // Assume xmlText contains the example XML
    console.log("ParserVideo,",xml_Img);
}) .catch((error) => {
    console.log("ParserEx",error);
});
```

I can see in console window

> WorkingTillHere

But it does not execute `XMLParser().parseFromString(responseJson);` and am getting console log

> ParserEx TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Same code works perfectly alright with this URL link `fetch('http://teststream.airtango.de/theo/vast.xml')`

Comment: I think you should call an async to fetch data from http request, 
try to add "await fetch" and add async in front of your function

Comment: @GaneshCauda - why? the `.then` chain gets called when appropriate

Comment: the only difference I can see in the raw XML is that where it **works** the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` are on their own lines - whereas in the data that fails you have `<Error><![CDATA[ ... blah blah blah ...]]></Error>` in one line - what is XMLParser? is it [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xml-parser)?

Comment: all the chain will be called, but if you not using asynchronous it will be no data on your response. You can try to use several approach to work with asynchronous function, use async/await, promise or callback, but if want a simple one just use async and await. You can find how to write it here : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: no ... it's the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` that throws it

Comment: are you sure there is data in your responseJson?

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly XMLParser is the same one you identified

Comment: oops, hang on try `xml_Img = new XMLParser().parseFromString(responseJson.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n'));`

Comment: @GaneshCauda yeah I can see data in responseJson in console window.

Comment: @GaneshCauda I have made my function "async" and applied await fetch but problem remained same

Comment: @GaneshCauda - you clearly don't understand promise `.then` chains

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad sir, i thought the code was just a simple fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-xml-parser does not understand the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

header. So, in general terms, you could

```
fetch('https://ad13.adfarm1.adition.com/banner?sid=3915124&wpt=X.xml')
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((xmlText) => {
    // remove <?xml  ... etc header because react-xml-parser chokes on it
    if (xmlText.toLowerCase().substr(0,5) == '<?xml') {
        xmlText = xmlText.split(/\?>\r{0,1}\n{0,1}/).slice(1).join('?>\n');
    }
    console.log("WorkingTillHere",xmlText)
    xml_Img = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xmlText);    // Assume xmlText contains the example XML
    console.log("ParserVideo,",xml_Img);
}) .catch((error) => {
    console.log("ParserEx",error);
});
```

> The above would only catch it if the very first 5 characters are `<?xml` ... that may be a little naive on my part. However, I believe the authors of `react-xml-parser` should handle `<?xml ... ?>` in their code :p
>
> Looking at the source to xmlParser, it seems they DO try to handle it, but obviously fail

Note, changing line 8 of xmlParse.js from

```
if (tags[i].indexOf('?xml')) {
```

to

```
if (tags[i].indexOf('?xml') < 0 && tags[i].length > 0) {
```

solves the issue too :p

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work .... [your Code](https://ibb.co/mUoRaQ) and the [Output is here](https://ibb.co/cxWevQ)

Comment: Actually, try the slight variation to the code I just updated

Comment: @RaihanAbbas - updated code again to be more forgiving of different types of "end of line"

Comment: My bad...It actually worked...Idk somehow console window didn't update...please ignore above comment..I have uploaded updated screenshot of your code's output [here](https://ibb.co/nhoON5) ...apologies @Jaromanda X